# How to make Tensorflow-lite available for the entire system in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, bash, ubuntu, cmake, tensorflow-lite

My tflite directory is as follows:

```
/home/me/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/
```

However, I fail to import it in my C++ project:

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h" // getting a not found error
```

How can I add resolve this error? My assumption is that I'd need to add the tflite to my bash to make it available for all of my projects. How can I add tflite to the bash file?

This is my CMAKE file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(mediafile_device_crossverification)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(OpenCV FOUND 1)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable(mediafile_device_crossverification main.cpp src/VideoProcessing.cpp src/VideoProcessing.h)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various options:

First option: Install/copy the tensorflow header files to e.g. `/urs/local/include` that folder is usually in the system include path by default.

Second option: GCC has some environment variables that can be used to modify the system include path. `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, your can add them to `.bashrc` to set them when you login. See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html

Third option is to add `/home/me/tensorflow_src` to the include path in the CMakefile.

When searching the include path `#include <tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h>` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really make it available for the entire system with the way TFLite's CMake is currently configured.

There's [a section](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#create_a_cmake_project_which_uses_tensorflow_lite) in TFLite's documentation which shows you how to build a project depending on it.

[A bit further up](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#step_5_build_tensorflow_lite) there's also a note why the library cannot be built stand-alone for time time being:

> Note: This generates a static library libtensorflow-lite.a in the current directory but the library isn't self-contained since all the transitive dependencies are not included. To use the library properly, you need to create a CMake project. Please refer the "Create a CMake project which uses TensorFlow Lite" section.